# What is the specification for generating authorization code for OAuth2?

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, jwt, authorization

I am writing a OAuth2 provider, and I am trying to generate the authorization code according to the spec here.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.1.2

> code
> REQUIRED.  The authorization code generated by the
> authorization server.  The authorization code MUST expire
> shortly after it is issued to mitigate the risk of leaks.  A
> maximum authorization code lifetime of 10 minutes is
> RECOMMENDED.  The client MUST NOT use the authorization code
>
> Hardt                        Standards Track                   [Page
> 26]
>
> RFC 6749                        OAuth 2.0                   October
> 2012
>
> ```
>      more than once.  If an authorization code is used more than
>      once, the authorization server MUST deny the request and SHOULD
>      revoke (when possible) all tokens previously issued based on
>      that authorization code.  The authorization code is bound to
>      the client identifier and redirection URI.
> ```

But what encoding or decoding protocol should I use exactly? Is it free for the provider to decide?

Answer (score 1):

The specification says nothing about encoding the authorization code, so it is up to the developer to decide. However, this is just a code; it contains no data that you should encode. The client application uses this code as-is, so there is no need to process it (e.g. decoding).

Comment: I am wondering encoding is because the spec ask us to bound the authorization code to the client identifier, redirection URI and time. And as I have used something like keycloak previously, I guess they have included those information inside that code by encoding?

Comment: in the response for the /auth call, the response is the **code only** (and if you insist, you can add there also state). see this: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.1.2